# Home Sharing not working with iPhone 5 iOS 6

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, home-sharing

Home sharing is not working on my iPhone : I can't see any 'shared' option in both music and videos app while I have activated Home sharing with the same ID on both my Mac and my iPhone.   
I have a MacBookPro with the latest version of iTunes and an iPhone 5 with the latest OS. 
I have tried to relaunch iTunes, turn off home sharing, sign out on my iPhone and start again the whole process without any result. And there's no issue with my router or firewall, I've checked all this. 
Does someone have any idea or tip to solve this problem ? 
Thanks a lot !

*Edit - 08/10 12:03 GMT* 
I set up Home Sharing on a second computer (with Windows XP) with the same Apple ID. I can see its library on both my mac and my iphone but I'm still unable to see my Mac library on the other devices. So, I think that the problem may be that my Mac "doesn't want" to share but is able to "receive". Any idea ? 
 Thanks

Comment: Both devices are part of the same WiFi network I assume?

Comment: I assume File Sharing is on, and set up correctly (AFP) with shared folders and users.

Comment: Yes both devices are part of the same Wifi network and all other services like syncing over the air or remote are working fine. File sharing was off; it's now on, what do you mean by 'set up correctly' ? are there specific settings for home sharing to work ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It's finally working. I quit all the services syncing over the air such as dropbox, evernote, wunderlist and bitTorrent Sync and restart my computer. It's working fine.
I've still no idea why it was not working before.
Thanks to you anyway